# Cant load profile with Selenium 2.44 and FF32 in python 3.2

Tags: python, selenium, cygwin

With Python 3.2 (in Cygwin) and Selenium 2.44 and FF32 (and FF33), Win8.1 64 bit following code

`browser = webdriver.Firefox()`

throws error

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 105, in _wait_until_connectable  
self.kill()  
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: %s If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I searched google, and found similar problems, but all experts suggested to upgrade selenium to latest and I have done so. I tried checking with FF 24, 28, but could not solve. Pl help me

Answer (score 0):

Looks like selenium's profile path handling is problematic in Cygwin

temporary hacking is

In cygwin_dir\lib\python3.2\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_binary.py, replace path by following line

```
def _start_from_profile_path(self, path):
          self._firefox_env["XRE_PROFILE_PATH"] = Popen(["cygpath", "-w",  path], stdout=PIPE).stdout.read().decode("utf-8").rstrip()
```